# Android: hand keystore over to different developer

Tags: android, keystore

I developed an android project for a customer which I signed with my own generated keystore.

Now I'd like to hand over the project to a different developer; (how) is it possible for him to sign the app and submit it to the market - without my keystore? Can I generate a file for him or how does that work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies) is detailed in the Android documentation:

> Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you
>   will want to continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or
>   set of certificates, if you want users to upgrade seamlessly to the
>   new version. When the system is installing an update to an
>   application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with
>   those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly,
>   including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows
>   the update. If you sign the new version without using matching
>   certificates, you will also need to assign a different package name to
>   the application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a
>   completely new application.

This basically means that any developer will need to sign updates with your keystore, or users won't be able to install the new version.

You can modify the passwords for your keystore but you generating a new keystore will cause problems for your users. If you  generate a new keystore, you'll have to remove the app from the Market and submit a new version. Existing users will *not* be able to upgrade - they'll need to uninstall and install the new version.

Comment: okay... that's not what I wanted to hear but I was afraid that it's this way... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. if you can want to give your keystore it's possible for that you need to give their details like alias name, password etc.
2. Another developer can create there own keystore on his way

Comment: @1 - I don't want to give him my details... @2 - but if he generates his own keystore, it's not possible to bring update the app, or is there a way to do it nevertheless?

Answer (score 0):

Application signing gives you the possibility to make updates to the application. If the application v1.0 is signed with one certificate and application v1.1 is signed with different certificate - your users won't see the update notification, it will appear like a new application. Who should own the keystore is not as important, as fact that every update must be signed with the same certificate. In fact, the owner of the certificate must be the publisher: if you're the publisher - sign it with your certificate, if the customer publishes the application - sign it with his certificate. Hope this helps.

Comment: that's my question... I signed the first versions with my certificate (was probably a mistake...). Now I'd like the new developer to sign the updates himself (so I'm out of the project) - is there no possibility?

Comment: @swalkner, you are the publisher of the app? will the next version be published from your account?

Comment: I'm the current publisher, yes. I don't mind if the updates are from my account (preferrably not). The most important thing is that it appears like an update to the users, NOT a new version.

Comment: @swalkner, then you should hand your certificate to the new developer, or sign every version yourself - no other solutions, probably..

Comment: I think you can create a new password and just give him your certificate. That would be the best solution, wouldn't it?